# python sys.exit can't break the main

Tags: python, exception, program-entry-point, exit

When I have a except in `memcache.Client`, I can capture the exception, but `mc.getstats` still exec, what should I do to stop the main when have an exception?

```
def main():
    if 'host' not in dir():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
    if 'port' not in dir():
        port = '11211'

    server = host + ':' + port

    try:
        mc = memcache.Client([server], debug=1,socket_timeout=3)
        result = mc.get_stats()
        mcstat = result[0][0]
        print mcstat
    except Exception,e:
        print e
        sys.exit(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except:
        sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: are you sure that `mc = memcache.Client([server], debug=1,socket_timeout=3)` is blocking?

Comment: Of course, your code has 40,000 errors before it ever gets to any exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: _When I have a except in memcache.Client_ Great.  How about some details?  1) What do you do to produce the error?, and 2) What is the error message?

Comment: @tcaswell, It does not.  That line just creates the client, and the client is subsequently used to set or get values from the server(s).  If creating the client throws an error, main() will end and mc.get_stats() will not execute.

Comment: yes ,i tried this script with some wrong arguments,but it can't stop the main function after exceptions,like this: MemCached: MemCache: inet:172.16.181.67:30220: connect: Connection refused.  Marking dead.
list index out of range

Comment: mc exceptions :MemCached: MemCache: inet:172.16.181.67:30220: connect: Connection refused. Marking dead. next error because mcstat = result[0][0]

Comment: _yes ,i tried this script with some wrong arguments,_  What wrong arguments?  How did you decide which portions of the error message to post?  Were you asked to post random portions of the error message?  Why did you post the error messages in the comments?  Did you want to make it as hard as possible for anyone to read them?  What is your strategy for getting help on a programming forum?  It seems like your strategy is to obfuscate everything and make it as hard as possible for anyone to help you.  I suggest you adopt new tactics.

Comment: i'sorry about that ,i will take a new topic for this

Answer (score 0):

```
import memcache
import sys


def main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 11211

my_server = "{}:{}".format(host, port)

try:
    mc = memcache.Client(
       my_server   #<**** Should be an array
    )

    result = mc.get_stats()
    mcstat = result[0][0]
    print mcstat
except ValueError, e:
    print "Mission control: There was a problem..."
    print e
    sys.exit(3)

--output:--
Mission control: There was a problem...
Unable to parse connection string: "1"
```